# Magic is happening when numpy array is altering by C function

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I'm trying to pass numpy array into the C function where I want to change array's values. But I have to multiply index by 2 to get it to work correctly. Assigning a value to an odd index (let it be `i`) leads to assigning a rubbish to index `(i-1)/2`. Here is the source code.

C:

```
#include "assign_array.h"

void assign(int *arr, int i) {
    arr[i] = 2017;
}
```

Python:

```
import ctypes, numpy
lib2 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./assign_array.so')
for i in range(5):
    array = numpy.zeros(8, dtype = int)
    ptr = array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    print('i = {}:'.format(i))
    lib2.assign(ptr, i)
    print(array)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF5x6.png)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *exactly* rubbish: `2047` is `0x7e1`, and `8662949036032` is `0x7E100000000`.  It looks as though you are mixing different C compilers (or flags supplied to C compilers), so that Python believes that `int` is 64 bits, but your C compiler believes that `int` is 32 bits.  Though, in fact, `int` in Python is not guaranteed to match `int` in a C compiler; it might more typically match `long`.

According to [the numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), `dtype` can be specified as `numpy.int32` to refer specifically to a 32-bit `int`.  That might be the simplest method of dealing with this, or of course you could change the C code to use `long` (assuming 64-bit `long`s in your C compiler's settings).

Comment: I compile this way: `gcc -shared -o assign_array.so -fPIC assign_array.c`

Comment: That suggests (though does not prove) that you're using a Linux/Unix-ish system, so probably your base Python uses C `long` for its internal `int` type, and your base C compiler has 64-bit `long`.  Other C compilers are similar.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: see update with parenthetical: Python `int` is most likely mapped to C `long`. (It's true that 64-bit `int` is rare; Cray was one of those systems.)

Comment: Oh, setting dtype to numpy.int32 solved the problem. Thank you.